# Overriding basic signals (SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGKILL??) in Python

Tags: python, linux, signals

I'm writing a program that adds normal UNIX accounts (i.e. modifying /etc/passwd, /etc/group, and /etc/shadow) according to our corp's policy. It also does some slightly fancy stuff like sending an email to the user.

I've got all the code working, but there are three pieces of code that are very critical, which update the three files above. The code is already fairly robust because it locks those files (ex. /etc/passwd.lock), writes to to a temporary files (ex. /etc/passwd.tmp), and then, overwrites the original file with the temporary. I'm fairly pleased that it won't interefere with other running versions of my program or the system useradd, usermod, passwd, etc. programs.

The thing that I'm most worried about is a stray ctrl+c, ctrl+d, or kill command in the middle of these sections. This has led me to the signal module, which seems to do precisely what I want: ignore certain signals during the "critical" region.
I'm using an older version of Python, which doesn't have signal.SIG_IGN, so I have an awesome "pass" function:

```
def passer(*a):
    pass
```

The problem that I'm seeing is that signal handlers don't work the way that I expect. 
Given the following test code:

```
def passer(a=None, b=None):
pass

def signalhander(enable):
    signallist = (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGQUIT, signal.SIGABRT, signal.SIGPIPE,       signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGKILL)
    if enable:
        for i in signallist:
            signal.signal(i, passer)
    else:
        for i in signallist:
            signal.signal(i, abort)
    return


def abort(a=None, b=None):
    sys.exit('\nAccount was not created.\n')
    return
signalhander(True)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
print('Enabled')
time.sleep(10)   # ^C during this sleep
```

The problem with this code is that a ^C (SIGINT) during the time.sleep(10) call causes that function to stop, and then, my signal handler takes over as desired. However, that doesn't solve my "critical" region problem above because I can't tolerate whatever statement encounters the signal to fail.

I need some sort of signal handler that will just completely ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT.
The Fedora/RH command "yum" is written is Python and does basically exactly what I want. If you do a ^C while it's installing anything, it will print a message like "Press ^C within two seconds to force kill." Otherwise, the ^C is ignored. I don't really care about the two second warning since my program completes in a fraction of a second.

Could someone help me implement a signal handler for CPython 2.3 that doesn't cause the current statement/function to cancel before the signal is ignored?

As always, thanks in advance.

---

Edit: After S.Lott's answer, I've decided to abandon the signal module.

I'm just going to go back to `try: except:` blocks. Looking at my code there are two things that happen for each critical region that cannot be aborted: overwriting file with file.tmp and removing the lock once finished (or other tools will be unable to modify the file, until it is manually removed). I've put each of those in their own function inside a `try:` block, and the `except:` simply calls the function again. That way the function will just re-call itself in the event of `KeyBoardInterrupt` or `EOFError`, until the critical code is completed.
I don't think that I can get into too much trouble since I'm only catching user provided exit commands, and even then, only for two to three lines of code. Theoretically, if those exceptions could be raised fast enough, I suppose I could get the "maximum reccurrsion depth exceded" error, but that would seem far out.

Any other concerns?

Pesudo-code:

```
def criticalRemoveLock(file):
    try:
        if os.path.isFile(file):
            os.remove(file)
        else:
            return True
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
        return criticalRemoveLock(file)
def criticalOverwrite(tmp, file):
    try:
        if os.path.isFile(tmp):
            shutil.copy2(tmp, file)
            os.remove(tmp)
        else:
            return True
     except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
        return criticalOverwrite(tmp, file)
```

Comment: Retrying is a really bad idea.  You want to undo all the work and reset things to the way they were when you started.  Forcing the operation to complete in the presence of Keyboard interrupts makes your program behave badly.  Cleaning up and provided a nice "Nothing got Done" error is much better.  Why not just clean up like every other program that attempts critical things?

Comment: @S.Lott. There are two situations where retrying is absolutely mandatory: removing lock and tmp files. You simply can't leave those files or else users won't be able to run the program properly next time. That is cleaning up. I take it a small step further because cleaning up (rm file.tmp file.lock) doesn't take longer than mv file.tmp file; rm file.lock. I have the "account was not created" for most of the application. It's just these three critical parts. Once the app gets there, I want to treat the modifications as atomic. Even if I decide to revert, that has to retry until successful.

Comment: Sorry.  "retrying is absolutely mandatory" is false.  Retrying is something you'd like to do.  Lots of applications crash, leave locks and temporaries, which the application cleans up next time it runs -- or reports an error indicating that the app is still running or had crashed.  I've deleted lots of lock files from crashed apps.  Often, those apps write a PID file to help find if it's still running.  Deleting work files is far from "mandatory".  It's merely desirable, and a bad desire at that.

Comment: @S.Lott. I don't think you understand what I'm doing at all. Sure, if an application legitimately crashes or gets an uninterpretable signal (SIGKILL), there's nothing that you can do reliably and could end up in infinite loops. If I kept retrying an `os.remove()` operation even after getting `IOError` that would be a mistake. However, I'm catching ^C and ^D. There are lots of programs that make these signal unavailable. ^C,^D are available for most of my program but at some point I have to (in DB terms) "commit" or "rollback" the changes. These are atomic operations.

Comment: Sorry. "retrying is absolutely mandatory" is false.  I think the recursion is ill-advised.

Answer (score 3):

There is no real way to make your script really save. Of course you can ignore signals and catch a keyboard interrupt using `try: except:` but it is up to your application to be idempotent against such interrupts and it must be able to resume operations after dealing with an interrupt at some kind of savepoint.

The only thing that you can really to is to work on temporary files (and not original files) and move them after doing the work into the final destination. I think such file operations are supposed to be "atomic" from the filesystem prospective. Otherwise in case of an interrupt: restart your processing from start with clean data.

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks for the response. I am currently using temporary and lock files. See my edit above with my solution.